# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (393613, 50)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a error in Keras and I can't find the solution. I have searched the whole internet and I have still no answer ^^
Here is my Code.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=X.values.shape))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The error is the second line. It says "ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (393613, 50)"
The Shape of my Dataframe X is correct.
And when I try to train the model the Error pops up

```
model.fit(X.values, Y.values, batch_size=200, epochs=10, validation_split=0.05)
```

I hope someone could help me :-)

[EDIT]
Btw. here is the model.summary()

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 393613, 32)        10624

---

lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 393613, 32)        8320

---

lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 32)                8320

---

## dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                330

Total params: 27,594
Trainable params: 27,594
Non-trainable params: 0

---

Kind regards Niklas.

Comment: can you share a sample of `X`.

Comment: try: `X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xfKsXUhZ

Comment: got it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704435/error-when-checking-model-input-expected-lstm-1-input-to-have-3-dimensions-but

Comment: It dosen't work :( Error: ValueError: Must pass 2-d input

Comment: Change your models first layer to this `model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X.values.shape[1],)))` and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While initialising the first layer you are passing 2 values as input_shape =`X.values.shape`

keras already expects number of rows per batch as NONE. At runtime this value is determined by `batch_size=` (200 in your case)

So basically it internally changed shape of input for layer 1 as 
`NO_OF_FEATURES, NO_OF_ROWS_IN_DATA_SET, NO_OF_ROWS_PER_BATCH`

To fix this all you have to do is pass 1 parameter as `input_shape`, which is no of features. Keras already accepts `NONE` as a placeholder for no of rows per batch.

So `input_shape=(X.values.shape[1],)` should do the trick.

`model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X.values.shape[1],)))`

Answer (score 0):

You have made two mistakes:

1. LSTM processes sequential data. That is the input data to LSTM is 3 dimensional. In, your 1st lstm layer you set input_shape = X.values.shape which is wrong because input_shape you have to specify number of timesteps and number of features i.e.  input_shape = (num_time_steps,num_features). Your rows of array are not your time steps. The rows basically indicate the batch number. As far as syntax is concerned, this is still right and you will not get any error while compiling the code.
2. You have to reshape your data set so that it is 3 dimensional i.e. batch_size,time_step,feature. You can easily that using numpy.reshape as follows:

   `X_train_arr = numpy.reshape(X.values,(X.values.shape[0],1,X.values.shape[1]))`

   This is assuming you have only one time steps. if you have more time steps than 
   you will need to do more tweaking.