# Keras and Error: Setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a problem with the input of multiple data sources in my neural network. My dataframe is:

```
                           0  1  2                   3   4  
0        [True, True, False]  3 -1  [False, True, True]  1
```

The input is related to the first 4 columns, the output is the last one.
When I train my neural network I get `Setting an array element with a sequence.`

```
def network():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(output_dim=50, activation='relu', input_dim=4))
        model.add(Dense(output_dim=50, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(output_dim=50, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(output_dim=1, activation='softmax'))
        opt = RMSprop(lr=0.00025)
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt)
        return model

    data = pd.DataFrame()
    state = [0]*3
    for i in range(3):
        state[i]= random.choice([True, False])
    move = random.randint(1,4)
    reward = random.choice([-1, -10, 10])
    future_state = [0]*3
    for i in range(3):
        future_state[i] = random.choice([True, False])
    Q = 1
    array = [state, move, reward, future_state, Q]

    data = data.append([array])
    training = data.drop([4], axis = 1)
    target = data[4]
    model = network()
    model.fit(training,target,epochs=2)
```

Python traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Documents/PycharmProjects/SnakeGA/try.py", line 33, in <module>
    model.fit(training,target,epochs=2)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 845, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1485, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1140, in _fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2075, in __call__
    feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1104, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 492, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Is this due to the fact that I have arrays in some columns, and integers in other columns? I thought Keras could handle that, but maybe I'm wrong. It's not clear to me how to handle concatenated data from multiple sources.
Thank you!

Comment: The error is produced inside numpy, not keras. It is unclear which part of your code produces it, you should include full code and the python traceback.

Comment: You are right, I edited including the full code and the traceback. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @MauroComi I'm having this same issue! Seems to be a problem when rows in the training set contain values mixed between numeric and array...if I remove the columns that contain array values then it works

Comment: Why would you want to mix numeric and array in the same column? For example, what would it mean if the 1st row is "3" and the 2nd row is "[0,1,0]"?

Comment: @JLewkovich You and Mauro are misunderstanding the concept of input values (and neurons in a NN): basically the input to the models are always a set of numerical values. It corresponds to a set of neurons where each neuron has a **single numerical value** as its output. So this means that you can't consider `[True, True, False]` or `[False, True, True]` as an individual input value. Rather, they both consist of 3 separate values (or you can convert them to one or multiple values). As @shadi has pointed out in her answer, one approach is to flatten the array so you have 8 input values (not 4).

Comment: @today The problem with flattening is in my case, I have at least 5 categorical columns, some of them have hot encodings that are arrays of 10000 length. To flatten all of those and append to the training set would create a very wide training set. Also, the flattening approach was very hard coded and not scalable. I was hoping there was some other way to process a training set that contains both numeric and categorical data. Perhaps moving on from a simple NN to something like LSTM? I just haven't figured it out yet, maybe it requires a new stackoverflow post.

Comment: @JLewkovich The description of your data is not clear to me. I also suggest you to ask a new question with enough information about the structure and format of the data and what you want to achieve. You have a much higher chance of getting an answer in that way.

Comment: @today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250124/mixing-numerical-and-categorical-data-into-keras-sequential-model-with-dense-lay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list inside the numpy array needs to be flattened before insertion.

`array` is `[[False, False, True], 4, -10, [False, True, False], 1]` in the OP implementation,

and should be flattened to `[False, False, True, 4, -10, False, True, False, 1]`.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/shadiakiki1986/173dd44fd7fec7c202605c596069e604) is a working jupyter notebook demonstrating this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, convert the input array into numpy array and convert the categorical boolean inputs into numbers. Then, give input dimension = 8 instead of 4.

Comment: It doesn't work, the error is the same. After converting, the numpy array contains `[list[1,0,1], 3, -1, [0,1,1]]` and it gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to input 2 different types of data to the neuron of a neural network. Neural networks isn't a magical box to throw random information into it and expect it to give a reasonable output.

NN's take only numbers as input. When you flatten your data

`[False, False, True, 4, -10, False, True, False, 1]` to this format, what you are effectively doing is converting it into this 
`[0,0,1,4,-10,0,1,0,1]`.

I am not really sure what you want from this data but, if you want only 5 features, you can take the majority outcome for those with binary values.

```
arr = [[False, False, True], 4, -10, [False, True, False], 1]
```

can be converted to

```
arr = [False,4,-10,False,1]
```

which effectively means your input is

```
arr=[0,4,-10,0,1]
```

But, before you do this, be sure what you're trying to do makes sense. You need to be able to answer questions like "what does each value represent?", "do i need to normalize the data?", "Would True/False in this dataset make sense?".