# Keras Neural Network model for binary classification with 3D tensor time series as input

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am building a NN model using keras and tensorflow for time series binary classification. This is how my input looks like, with a shape of (124,4,591):

```
      |      Col 1      |    Col 2        |    Col 3        |    Col 4        |
Row 1 | [x1, ..., x591] | [x1, ..., x591] | [x1, ..., x591] | [x1, ..., x591] |
Row 2 | [x1, ..., x591] | [x1, ..., x591] | [x1, ..., x591] | [x1, ..., x591] |
Row 3 | [x1, ..., x591] | [x1, ..., x591] | [x1, ..., x591] | [x1, ..., x591] |
```

I split my data into `X_train`, `X_test`, `y_train` and `y_test`. I also encoded my labels from `['True', 'False']` into `[0, 1]` using `LabelEncoder()` and `OneHotEncoder()`.

```
x = np.stack((np.vstack(x[:,0]),np.vstack(x[:,1]),np.vstack(x[:,2]),np.vstack(x[:,3])))
x = x.reshape((124,4,591))
y = table_raw_ptpt['Binding Known']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)
```

`X_train.shape` returns *(86, 4, 591)*.
Encoding for labels:

```
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded_train = label_encoder.fit_transform(array(y_train))
integer_encoded_test = label_encoder.fit_transform(array(y_test))

onehot_encoded_y_train = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
integer_encoded_train = integer_encoded_train.reshape(len(integer_encoded_train), 1)
onehot_encoded_y_train = onehot_encoded_y_train.fit_transform(integer_encoded_train)

onehot_encoded_y_test = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
integer_encoded_test = integer_encoded_test.reshape(len(integer_encoded_test), 1)
onehot_encoded_y_test = onehot_encoded_y_test.fit_transform(integer_encoded_test)
```

`onehot_encoded_y_train.shape` returns *(86, 2)*.

Here is my NN:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(86, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,591)))
model.add(Dense(43, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer = 'adam',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

It works. But when I try to fit the X_train I get an error:

> Error when checking target: expected dense_227 to have shape (1,) but
>   got array with shape (2,)

The mentioned layer is the output layer. As far as I understood, the output shape is incorrect. I tried using `Flattern()` in between the layers, and even tried a `Reshape(1,)`. But since I'm a beginner at this, I don't fully understand what I have to add to control my data shape in the NN in order to obtain the output I need.

I managed to make it work with `softmax`, but I need the `sigmoid` to work too so I can have a final prediction afterward (True or False / 1 or 0).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the part of the code where you define `y_train`, `y_test`?

Comment: Sure. I will edit the code and add this information.

Comment: @IsabellaNavarro Since you are doing binary classification, the label for each sample should be either zero or one and not `[0, 1]` or `[1, 0]`. In other words, the `y_train` should have a shape of `(86,)` and not `(86,2)`.

Comment: Oh I see the point there. But how can I do the encoding for my labels then? Any tip?

Comment: I will try with the integer encoded. :D

Comment: @IsabellaNavarro If `y_train` consists of `True` and `False` values then you don't need to change it. Just pass it to the `fit` method. Plus, use "@[user_name]" at the beginning of your comment when you are replying to a specific user. Otherwise he/she will not be notified of your comment.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you handle your ground truth data `y` . The following model is working with random data with your real data you have to encode `y` as *one-hot* with 4 values and assign this one-hot encoding the ground truth vector `y` which has to have the shape (124,**4**,1) note the **4** ( i use 124 samples here )

So `y` has to have 4 dimensions `y1, y2, y3, y4`. In the following is shown how your ground truth logical values `00, 01, 10,11` that are pairs have to be encoded and assigned to the 4 dimensional target vector `y`:

```
0 0 ->      0001  -> y1=0, y2=0, y3=0, y4=1
0 1 ->      0010  -> y1=0, y2=0, y3=1, y4=0
1 0 ->      0100  -> y1=0, y2=1, y3=0, y4=0
1 1 ->      1000  -> y1=1, y2=0, y3=0, y4=0
```

this handling of logical values can be illustrated with a *Karnaugh-Veitch map* ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map  ), each square in the map is equivalent to one one-hot encoded logical value.

you have to write a function that translates the combination of your logical values `00,01,10,11` into a one-hot encoded feature **vector** of dimension 4 like above

with `y` encoded like this the model can be built like

```
from random import randint
from random import seed
import math
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense


# generating random data, replace this with your data

X = np.random.rand(124,4,591)

y = np.random.randint(2,size=(124,4)) # replace this with your ground truth feature vector

y=y.reshape(124,4,1)



# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704435/error-when-checking-model-input-expected-lstm-1-input-to-have-3-dimensions-but


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(86, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,591)))
model.add(Dense(43, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=10)
```

Critical is that `y` has the same second dimension like `X` here namely 4, this can be achieved by encoding the logical values of your ground truth like above

this is not done in the code above because i do  not know your data, in the code random data of correct dimensionality is used