# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iterrows' while predicting value using lstm in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, lstm

I have a dataset with three inputs and trying to predict next value of X1 with the combination of previous inputs values.

My three inputs are X1, X2, X3, X4.

So here I am trying to predict next future value of X1. To predict the next X1 these four inputs combination affect with:

```
X1 + X2 - X3 -X4
```

I wrote this code inside the class. Then I wrote the code to run the lstm . After that I wrote the code for predict value. Then it gave me this error. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

my code:

```
def model_predict(data):
pred=[]
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    val = row['X1']
    if np.isnan(val):
        data.iloc[index]['X1'] = pred[-1]
        row['X1'] = pred[-1]
        f = row['X1','X2','X3','X4']
        s = row['X1'] - row['X2'] + row['X3'] -row['X4']
        val = model.predict(s)
        pred.append(val)
return np.array(pred)
```

After lstm code then I wrote the code for predict value:

```
pred = model_predict(x_test_n)
```

Gave me this error:

```
  ` ---> 5 pred = model_predict(x_test_n)

    def model_predict(data):
     pred=[]
  -->for index, row in data.iterrows():
        val = row['X1']
        if np.isnan(val):`     
   AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

Comment: This error speaks for itself, you need to transform `numpy.ndarray` to `pandas.DataFrame`

Comment: @Michael O. 3  First of all thank you for the fast reply. I didn't get what you are saying. Can you explain little bit more with a code, if you are okay?

Comment: What is `x_test_n`, I guess it is `numpy.ndarray`? If you want to handle it as Pandas dataframe, you need to convert it first, for example, like it is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763012/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-numpy-array-how-do-i-specify-the-index-colum

Comment: @MichaelO. It's my test set , to predict next value

Comment: @MichaelO. I wrote it as inside the class as pd dataframe and it gave me an error and code " data = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],index=data[1,:])" , error  "Must pass 2-d input"

Comment: In one place you have *X1 + X2 - X3 - X4*, but later *row['X1'] - row['X2'] +
row['X3'] - row['X4']*. Make up your mind where there should be **+** and where **-**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparenty, *data* argument of your function is a *Numpy* array, not a *DataFrame*.
*Data*, as a *np.ndarray*, has also no named columns.

One of possible solutions, keeping the argument as *np.ndarray* is:

- iterate over rows of this array using *np.apply_along_axis()*,
- refer to columns by indices (instead of names).

Another solution is to create a *DataFrame* from *data*, setting proper
column names and iterate on its rows.

**One of possible solutions how to write the code without DataFrame**

Assume that *data* is a *Numpy* table with 4 columns,
containing respectively *X1*, *X2*, *X3* and *X4*:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [10  8  1  3]
 [20  6  2  5]
 [31  3  3  1]]
```

Then your function can be:

```
def model_predict(data):
    s = np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: row[0] + row[1] - row[2] - row[3],
        axis=1, arr=data)
    return model.predict(s)
```

Note that:

- *s* - **all** input values to your model - can be computed in a single
  instruction, calling *apply_along_axis* for each row (axis=1),
- the predictions can also be computed "all at once", passing a *Numpy*
  vector - just *s*.

For demonstration purpose, compute *s* and print it.

Comment: So I have to write it in inside the class isn't if? If It is I wrote it and it gave me an error " Must pass 2-d input"   ,, I wrote the code is " data = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],index=data[1,:])"

Comment: You wrote *data=data[1:,1:],index=data[1,:]*. It actually means:
1. Drop the first row and column from *data*.
2. The index should be just the same as the first column of your DataFrame. Do you really want this?
I also noticed that you failed to pass column names, so default names will be consecutive numbers from 0 and your code still will break on an attempt to access a non-existing column.
Another hint: Error message shows that you passed only a **vector** not an **array**.
Make a test printout of your data and look whether it contains all needed columns and more than 1 row.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I can understand what you are saying. I am actually stuck with this code , and I can't go forward with this error. I am not having proper idea that how to change the code to run this. If you are okay to help me with the code , it will be really helpful to me go forward.

Comment: Before you call *model_predict*, make a printout of *data* and add a sample of it to your question. Then: 1. Decide which columns contain values for X1, X2, X3 and X4. 2. In *model_predict* create a DataFrame from *data*, passing column names (maybe the default index will be enough). 3. The loop using *iterrows* should run on rows from just this DataFrame.

Comment: Two questions to your code: 1. Your loop contains *f = row['X1','X2','X3','X4']*. What is the use of this variable?
2. What is the content (and type) of *model*?

Comment: And a hint to your code: If you refer to multiple columns from a row than column names should be in **double** brackets. Otherwise you will probably get an execution error.

Comment: f = row['X1','X2','X3','X4'] These are my four inputs , and according to the four inputs I am trying to predict the X1 value.  2. Model I am using LSTM

Comment: Before writing this code I wrote my data inside the dataframe . data= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['X1','X2','X3','X4'])
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format

Comment: @ Valdi_Bo Thank you for your great answer, when I applied , it gave me this error " Error when checking input: expected lstm_7_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1446, 4)"

Comment: Note that *s* is an array with one column (shape (n, 1), not (n, 4)).
Maybe the above error message is from some other line of code?
Check in documentation what should be the input in "set of predictions" case. Then prepare correct input, taking the pattern from my solution.
Read also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704435, it should give you the clue.