# Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (4, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

First of all, I know there are tons of questions similar like this; I've tried to do what the answers suggest, but seems like I do not know how to solve it. I have a `Keras Functional API model`:

```
lstm_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,4), name='lstm_input')
x = keras.layers.LSTM(50, name='lstm_0')(lstm_input)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name='lstm_dropout_0')(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(64, name='dense_0')(x)
x = keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid', name='sigmoid_0')(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(1, name='dense_1')(x)
output = keras.layers.Activation('linear', name='linear_output')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=lstm_input, outputs=output)

adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse')
```

And when I try to fit it, it jumps this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (4, 1)
```

This is my call to `fit`:

```
model.fit(X_aux['X_i'], X[i+1, 0])
# X_aux['X_i'].shape = (4, ) -- it's a numpy array
```

I've tried `np.reshape([X_aux['X_i1']], (4,1))`, where its new shape is `(4, 1)` but it does not work. How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when checking model input: expected lstm\_1\_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (339732, 29)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704435/error-when-checking-model-input-expected-lstm-1-input-to-have-3-dimensions-but)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your input_shape of X_aux['X-i'] is 3 dimensional.

The input of any RNN-based layer must be 3 dimensional where each axis is corresponded to `batch_size`, `time_step`, and `feature dimension` respectively.

The reason why reshaping to `(4, 1)` wouldn't help is that the reshaped tensor is still 2 dimension. You need 3.

Make sure you define `batch_size`, `time_step`, and `feature dimension` correctly and reshape X_aux['X-i'] and retrain the model again.